# Angular scope and select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a date filter in an angular project that I have built and it updates the date on scope for my results. I also have a couple of selects beside this that are used to pick month and year.

The date is stored in a scope variable.

When I update the calendar, it works fine and updates the dropdowns and when when I change the dropdown it works fine and will update the calendars.

My issue is that when I change the dropdown and then change the calendar date the scope variable updates but the select stays on the value that I had changed it to previously and will not update.

I have checked using boomerang and the scope variable is updating fine, just not updating the select dropdown.

I have tried resetting the array of objects for the dropdown and that still hasn't worked.

Here is what im working with:

```
<select
    ng-model="selectedStartMonth"
    ng-options="startMonth as startMonth for startMonth in startMonths"
    ng-change="changeDateDropdown('startMonth', selectedStartMonth);"
    ng-selected="selectedStartMonth"
></select>

<script>
    scope.$watchGroup(['start', 'end'], function(newValue, oldValue){
        scope.selectedStartMonth = moment(scope.start).format('MMMM');
        scope.selectedStartYear  = moment(scope.start).format('YYYY');
        scope.selectedEndMonth   = moment(scope.end).format('MMMM');
        scope.selectedEndYear    = moment(scope.end).format('YYYY');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you repro this in plnkr?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I think `newValue === oldValue` will never be `true` because you are comparing arrays, thus references, and they are not references to the same array.

Comment: That was left in from when these weren't arrays. It isn't used here.

Comment: Can you show us the datepicker code you are using? Sounds like a missing `$scope.$apply` there.

Comment: Im using the angular-datepicker directive from here: https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker. The bit that has me completely stumped is that it updates perfectly if you have not picked via the select yet.

Comment: Then my next hunch would be that `startMonths` contains something else than an array of strings (`['Jan', 'Feb', ...]`). The way `ng-options` works together with `ng-model` is that the value of `ng-model` has to be strictly equal (`===`) with a value from what's in `ng-options` for that specific `<option>` to be selected.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I have finally been able to get back to this. My array is just strings and the result of `scope.selectedStartMonth` is (`===`).